# Excel Add Text if Multiple Conditions

Tags: excel

I have data like the following. There are other columns as well but for simplicity, I am excluding those

> **Country | Company Name | Item**
>
> USA | Stackoverflow | A
>
> USA | Stackoverflow | B
>
> Canada | Stackoverflow | A
>
> USA | Someothercompany | A
>
> USA | Someothercompany | B
>
> USA | Someothercompany | A
>
> ...

I have a column that I just want to have the text `X` for every row of a single company if the country is `Canada`.

In my example above, because one of the countries for `Stackoverflow` is `Canada`, I want all rows that have `Stackoverflow` to have an `X`. Similarly because all of `Someothercompany` does not have `Canada` as a country, those will be left blank.

The outcome of what I am looking for in the example above would be:

> **Country | Company Name | Item | Reject**
>
> USA | Stackoverflow | A | X
>
> USA | Stackoverflow | B | X
>
> Canada | Stackoverflow | A | X
>
> USA | Someothercompany | A |
>
> USA | Someothercompany | B
>
> USA | Someothercompany | A

I have tried using the `Index` & `Match` functions but I have not had much luck for changing every row.

Comment: Because I feel that there must be a simple function (and there was)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formula will do what you want:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,"Canada",B:B,B2)>0,"X","")
```

[image]

The countifs() finds if there is any Canada with the company.  If it is greater than 0 it returns the "X".